# Remote desktop software that allows connection of multiple users concurrently

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, macos, remote-desktop

My team's remote device is a Linux machine running Ubuntu 20.04. We are looking for a remote desktop software with the following qualities:

- **multiple separate users concurrently** can connect and use the desktop
- **free** for non-commercial use
- client software is compatible with **Windows 10/11, MacOS, and Linux**
- preferably connections can be made when in **separate networks**, though this isn't required
- preferably easy to set up and use

We've tried the following programs, which unfortunately did not meet our needs:

- TeamViewer

  - this does not allow for multiple separate concurrent connections
- NoMachine

  - this does not allow for multiple separate concurrent connections
  - this does not allow for connections to be made when in separate networks, unless the remote device's network has port forwarding (ours does not, and we're unable to set that up as my team doesn't have control over the network configs)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as a free solution... I think you should lower your expectations and admit that you could maybe afford <$10/month

Comment: @Josem well, free solutions exist for single user connections. TeamViewer and NoMachine are examples. This is for non-commercial use, at an educational institution. However, if you do think there are no free options and you have ones that meet the other reqs while having a subscription model, please do share them.

Comment: Getscreen.me is the option I was thinking, but I haven't try it... perhaps you can play with it and share it with us.

Comment: IIRC, Google remote desktop can do multiple connection at once, maybe you can try them, https://remotedesktop.google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that meets our needs well: [xrdp](http://xrdp.org/). It's free (open source), compatible with all OSs as far as I can tell, has been easy to set up and use, allows multiple concurrent connections, and I think allows connecting to static IPs outside of one's network (though I haven't confirmed that part). It unfortunately needs port forwarding to connect to devices with dynamic IPs like NoMachine does, but other than that it has what we were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all parameters you should suit the software [Getscreen.me](https://getscreen.me/) It provides remote connection via a browser, works with Windows, Linux, Mac and Android. You can connect multiple users simultaneously and even create admin teams.

There is a 14-day trial, you can try all the features and decide for yourself whether this service is suitable for you. It's free for 2 devices, but as I understood you need more.